# What to do with <<First Name>> merge tag when posting a Mailchimp campaign message to Twitter?

Tags: twitter, mailchimp

Our Mailchimp account is connected with our Twitter account. When selecting "Autotweet campaign as" Mailchimp automatically tweets our campaign on Twitter. However, as there is no recipient first name or last name known in a tweet, the message looks bad. It looks like this: http://us3.campaign-archive2.com/?u=27333bc7e6f5335271a0b557e&id=616707cb9c

Do you know how to replace the <> merge tag with some default text, or simply remove it completely, when it appears on a web page that the tweet links to?

Answer (score 0):

You can [set a default value for the merge tag](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/set-default-merge-values-for-a-list), or use conditional merge tags to hide that merge tag from displaying on your campaign archive page: http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/archives/manage-content-and-privacy-in-campaign-archives